# Can a dishwasher and disposer be on the same 20 ampere circuit?

Tags: electrical

I am in the process of rewiring kitchen in a 1925 era farmhouse removing knob and tube. Have new 100 amp service and will soon pull 12/2 cu thhn to power .kitchen sink garbage disposer and dishwasher. Am considering placing these two applicances on one/same 20 amp gfci circuit. Would appreciate any thoughts as to propriety of doing so. Do these items need seperate circuits? Is it desireable to have these on own circuit or is that unnecessary. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a kitchen there are a minimum of 2 20 amp circuits required. Where I live a dedicated circuit is required for dishwashers, Most of the houses I have wired have 4 branch circuits or 5. I usually put the fridge on its own circuit, a microwave and the disposal on Thier own circuit, if there is a trash compactor the disposal and compactor. In some cases where a 120 outlet is needed for a gas stove or cooktop I will put that on the same as the microwave. There is not a code requirement for this many circuit but the permits only cost a couple dollars per breaker and a few extra feet of wire. I have had to upgrade quite a few kitchens over the years and only one I installed as the owner was pinching pennies and it cost him almost 3k to do what my proposal was at a 400$ savings up front.